# Access the Multiple Node inside Multiple Nodes in Vb.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, search, nodes

For the below XML, I need to get the `separately for each` (there are 2 nodes) and add it to a dictionary. I am trying to do using below code. But when I am trying to access the node I am getting the count as 4 (it takes both the). I need to extract occupants based on risk. Any hopes?

Here gives count as 4 when looping first node instead of 2 as 1st Risk contains 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the XPath to be relative to current node (Xpath query performed within current node context only), you need to add period/dot (`.`) at the beginning of the XPath, for example :

```
xPath = "/SearchResult/Risks/Risk"
......
......
'get Location from current <Risk>'
xmlNode = xmlNodeRisk.SelectSingleNode("./Location")
'get Occupant from current <Risk>'
xmlNodeChild1 = xmlNodeRisk.SelectNodes("./Occupants/Occupant")
'get Address from current <Location>'
XmlNodeAddress = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("./Address")
......
......
```